# Unison with macOS and times set to true (times = true)

Tags: macos, sync, timestamp, unison

I am using Unison for a 2-way sync between a MacBook Pro (macOS Sierra) and an external drive (Firewire). I am using the GUI version, Unison 2.48.

In the profile `.prf` I add `times = true`, however, the files' CREATION timestamps do not sync when a file is modified. Instead, the modification date is assumed as the creation date after the sync takes place. So, I end up with 2 equal files, but different creation timestamps.

Does anybody have any tips about this? Might this be an issue in macOS or could it just be me doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code for Unison, [only the modification dates are updated](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/blob/master/src/props.ml#L423) with the `times` option. macOS is one of [very few operating systems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91197/how-to-find-creation-date-of-file) that keep creation dates. While Unison supports some macOS-specific data (e.g. [resource forks](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/blob/master/src/osx.mli)), it won't synchronize creation dates.

Comment: That's a very good answer although, unfortunately for me, not the one I was willing to get. Thank you for taking the time to look at the code of Unison. I just would say that, if Unison does not deal with macOS in the way it is supposed to, than I guess it is not full compatible with such OS. Well, I will be looking somewhere else, then, which is a shame, because I was really enjoying Unison.